# Meteor search clear results

Tags: meteor

I would like to make Meteor clear the last query, it does not accumulate my research. If I search in the input "Nº Património" and then doir again in the "Código Informática", I want to clear the first query results. What is happening is that it brings together the first and the second query results. Summing up, i want to se query results independently.[Meteor search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62bCi.jpg)

**Template**

```html
<tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Nº Património</th>
        <th>Equipamento</th>
        <th>Utilizador</th>
        <th>Nº Helpdesk</th>
        <th>Data Aquisição</th>
        <th>Data Saída</th>
        <th>Ultima Alteração</th>
      </tr>
      {{#each pesquisaEquipamentos}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{npatrimonio}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{equipamento}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{utilizadores}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{helpdesk}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{daquisicao}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{dsaida}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{createdAt}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

**Helper**

```javascript
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.pesquisar.helpers({
    pesquisaEquipamentos: function() {
      return Equipamentos.find();
    }
  });

  Template.pesquisar.events({

    "keypress input": function(event, template) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var search = {};
        search.value = event.target.value
        search.name = event.target.name
        //console.log(search.name, search.value);
        Meteor.subscribe("pesquisaEquipamentos", search);
        event.target.value = '';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Publication**

```javascript
Meteor.publish("pesquisaEquipamentos", function(search) {
  //console.log(search.name);
  //console.log(search.value);
  switch (search.name) {
    case 'npatrimonio':
      return Equipamentos.find({
        npatrimonio: search.value
      });
      break;
    case 'cinformatica':
      return Equipamentos.find({
        cinformatica: search.value
      });
      break;
    default:
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stopping the subscription before you call it again:

```
var mySub;
Template.pesquisar.events({
  "keypress input": function(event, template) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      var search = {};
      search.value = event.target.value
      search.name = event.target.name
      if ( mySub ) mySub.stop(); // if you've previously subscribed clear those results
      mySub = Meteor.subscribe("pesquisaEquipamentos", search);
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
});
```